# How do I print a variable inside ""?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I print a variable within ""?
for example;

```
a = "test"
print"this is a (how do I input 'a' here?)"
```

Comment: use `print "this is a (how do I input '%s' here?)" % a`

Comment: @TamilSelvan op uses python 3.x

Comment: @AvinashRaj @idjaw you are right. python 3 has different syntax. try `print("this is a (how do I input ", a , "here?)")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use (Python 3)

```
print("this is a (how do I input ", a , "here?)")
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

For older version use

```
print "this is a (how do I input '%s' here?)" % a
```

See http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex5.html

Answer (score 4):

You should read the print [tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_print.php):

But what you are looking to do is this:

```
print("this is a {} here?".format(a))
```

If you are looking to put multiple variables in your string, you can simply do this:

```
print("this is a {0} here and {1} and also {2}?".format(a, b, c))
```

You could actually just write the line like this without the number specifications:

```
print("this is a {} here and {} and also {}?".format(a, b, c))
```

Being explicit with the numbers would be best if you were looking to re-order the placement of the arguments in the string, like this:

```
print("this is a {2} here and {0} and also {1}?".format(a, b, c))
```

So, in the above example, first string would be c, then a, then b.

For your particular case where you are trying to add quotes in your string, there are different ways you can do this. If you want double quotes, you can wrap with single quotes:

```
print('this is a "{2}" here and "{0}" and also "{1}"?'.format(a, b, c))
```

If you want single quotes, wrap with double quotes:

```
print("this is a '{2}' here and '{0}' and also '{1}'?".format(a, b, c))
```

Finally, there is the triple single quote:

```
print('''this is a '{2}' here and '{0}' and also '{1}'?'''.format(a, b, c))
```

Mix whichever type of quote:

```
print('''this is a "{2}" here and "{0}" and also '{1}'?'''.format(a, b, c))
```

Comment: Explicitly numbering isn't needed unless you're reordering usage, or reusing the same argument more than once. The second example could be three `{}` usages too.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was just trying to be more explicit for the sake of the example. I will make note of this tough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plus operator:

```
a = "test"
print"this is a " + a
```

See: https://pythonspot.com/python-strings/